# Find the intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find

$\langle\{(1,2,3,4),(1,1,1,3),(0,1,2,2)\}\rangle\cap\langle\{(1,0,-1,2),(2,3,0,1)\}\rangle$

this is, the intersection between the span of $\{(1,2,3,4),(1,1,1,3),(0,1,2,2)\}$ and the span of $\{(1,0,-1,2),(2,3,0,1)\}$.

Which is the easier way to do this?

My problem is that is a lot of vectors, so try to characterize the subspaces is too long.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V = \langle (1,2,3,4), (1,1,1,3), (0,1,2,2)\rangle$ and $W=\langle(1,0,−1,2),(2,3,0,1)\rangle$. Then I think the easiest way is to find basis for $V^{\perp}$ and $W^{\perp}$ and then solve the system consisting of the basis of $V^{\perp}$ and the basis of  $W^{\perp}$. All at all there are $3$ systems that have to be solved.

As answer I get $V^{\perp} = \langle(1,-2,1,0)\rangle$ and $W^{\perp} = \langle(2,-1,0,-1), (3,-2,3,0)\rangle$. So $V \cap W$ should be the space of solutions of the system:

\begin{array}{lcl} x_1-2x_2+x_3 & = & 0 \\ 2x_1-x_2-x_4 & = & 0 \\ 3x_1-2x_2+3x_3 & = & 0 \end{array}

Which is $V \cap W = \langle(1, 0, -1, 2)\rangle$.